# Update TrimTrialingBlanks in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

How do i change a column's `TrimTrialingBlanks` to Yes from No for a table in sql server for an already existing table?

I used this

`Update tabelename set TrimTrialingBlanks='yes';`

But this didn't work.

> TrimTrialingBlanks seems to be column properties and not a table
>   column.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what you are after is to change a fixed-width data type (e.g. CHAR) to VARCHAR, e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.foo ALTER COLUMN bar VARCHAR(32);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is some discussion here:  http://www.issociate.de/board/index.php?t=msg&th=144270&rid=0